# Subsonic template for SQLite is incorrect

Tags: sqlite, subsonic, subsonic3

The SQLite.ttinclude (for VB) should have

```
tbl.Schema="";
```

in the LoadTables procedure, otherwise the Struts.tt will not compile

```
Running transformation: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: objectToConvert
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.ToStringHelper.ToStringWithCulture(Object objectToConvert)
  at    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingBB4B38057266A6749A8A039E145DE2BB.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
```

I am using the lastest 3.0.0.3 zip from the subsonicproject.com website

Comment: Awesome, great.  Is there a question?  You should pass this on to Rob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please file this at http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues so you can track the status of this bug.  If you don't have account (or don't want to create one), just add a comment here and one of us will file it on your behalf.

Comment: My new years resolution for 2010 is to only regester with OpenId sites. Therefore, as github does not support OpenId I will not be raising a bug, sorry.